# Python BNCCorpusReader doesn't work with full bnc corpus

Tags: python, concatenation, corpus

What I'd like to do is simply read corpus in xml and append them all. I tried it with baby-bnc(2553) and successfully converted it into the plain text file but when I did with full-bnc(2554) or sampler(2551), I keep seeing this error: ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!

```
import nltk.corpus.reader.bnc as cor    
a=cor.BNCCorpusReader(root=r'BNC\2553\2553\download\Texts',fileids=r'[a-z]{3}/\w*\.xml') 
len(a.sents()) 
with open("2553.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8') as nf: 
    for s in a.sents(): 
        nf.write(' '.join(s)) 
    pass
```

It is supposed to show something like below (works well with baby-corpus)

```
a=cor.BNCCorpusReader(root=r'BNC\2553\2553\download\Texts',fileids=r'[a-z]{3}/\w*\.xml')     
In[18]: len(a.sents())
Out[18]: 280851
```

But with the full-corpus which I need to use, the result is always error.

```
b=cor.BNCCorpusReader(root=r'BNC\2554\Texts',fileids=r'[a-z]{3}/\w*\.xml')
In[18]: len(b.sents())     
ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!
```

Thinking there might be issues when downloading so I downloaded several times on different computers but it still doesn't work.

I'm desperately looking for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

They are having different folder structures. Try this one
fileids=r'[A-K]/\w*/\w*.xml'